# Should this question be closed?

Tags: discussion

While reviewing unanswered question  I came upon [this one](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/4535/repair-wooden-footboard-rail-mount).  The photo link is lost and there have not been any answers.  As a general procedure, should this type of question be identified and closed?

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing that out. Feel free to flag similar questions or vote to close, and comment if appropriate.